# Loop throught dynamicly generated options

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to find a way to loop through some dynamically generated options.I have tryed to do it like this:

```
console.log($("select#subcategory option").length);
$("select#subcategory option").each(function () {

            console.log($(this).val() + "ceva");
            if ($(this).val() == subcategoryId) {
                console.log($(this).val());
                $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
            }
});
```

BUt it seems jQUery does not see any of the generated items.I am using jquery 1.5.1.

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**

So far I have no luck in managing to select the generated elements.From the methods I have tryed so far I can tell that neither manages to see the dom elements that are dynamilt created.It is as If they are not there , but if I check with Firebug I can see them.Can this problem appear beucase I am creating them after an ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
$(document).find("select#subcategory option").each(function () {
    var subcategoryId = $('#subcategory').attr('id');
    console.log($(this).val() + "ceva");
    if ($(this).val() == subcategoryId) {
       console.log($(this).val());
       $(this).prop("selected", true);
    }
 });
```

Comment: this does not seem to work I have tryed several methods I found over the internet in all methods it seems jquery does not see the select options but if I check the dom they are there.Ca this be because I am creating them after an ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain vanilla javascript :

```
   var select = document.getElementById('subcategory');
   for (var i=0; i<select.options.length; i++) {
       console.log(select.options[i]);
       if (select.options[i].value==subcategoryId) {
            select.selectedIndex = i;
            break;
       }
   }
```